# Difficulty Installing SSL Cert Into Tomcat

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate

I’m having difficult installing an SSL cert into my Tomcat 9 Win7 dev environment.  As I understand Tomcat SSL the cert must be imported using the alias of the existing private key used when cert was created. 
I’ve obtained the cert from Godady using my LIUNX production system and following their instructions I created the keystore on my Win7 dev machine with the –genkey option, imported the root cert and imported the dev cert using the same alias that was used to create the keystore.

However, when I import the dev cert I get an error message that the key the import alias refers to is not compatible with the key the cert was generated with (-genkey option).

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match
```

I have the private key that was used to request the cert as a .key file, but it will not import into the keystore giving an error that the file is not a valid x509 certificate.  The private .key file is readable as a text file and formatted as:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- 
            …
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I'm also not sure the bundle cert I imported is the root cert or if I need another but I don't think that's causing this problem, it might be a challenge down the line when trying to actually use the cert.  These are the commands I used.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
REM Create the keystore
keytool -alias tomcat -keysize 2048 -genkey -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.keystore

REM Imnport the root cert
keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

REM Import the dev cert
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file my_dev_cert.crt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.  The important part is to create a temp keystore containing both the cert and private key then import the whole temp keystore into the destination tomcat keystore.  openssl is needed to do this.  Here's a recap of the steps that successfully installed a SSL cert into tomcat:

```
REM Run on LINUX.  This makes a new keystore with the cert and private key in it.  Then import the whole keystore into the Tomcat keystore
sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert.crt -inkey mycertsprivatekey.key -name myalias -out tempkeystore.p12

copy temp keystore to windows.

REM Run on Windows. Create the tomcat keystore
keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.keystore

REM Import the root cert
keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

REM Import the temp keystore with the real private key and cert into the real keystore
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass XXXXXX -destkeystore tomcat.keystore -srckeystore tempkeystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12

REM Check the keystore contents
keytool -list -keystore tomcat.keystore

REM Configure tomcat server.xml using the above -name option as the key alias

    <Connector 
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="/dev/ssl/tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="XXXXXX" keyAlias="myalias"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```